# Deducing a Taylor expansion in an arbitrary point from a MacLauren polynomial

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a function $f(x,y)=-2x^3 + 4y^3 +4xy+4x$ and I need to find a Taylor expansion, around the point $(-4,1)$ of this function.

Since the function is actually a polynomial, I know this representation is also its Taylor expansion, but around $(0,0)$ . Is there any way to calculate the Taylor series around $(-4,1)$ without having to calculate all the derivatives ? (i.e.- only by using the known form of the function )

Hope I made myself clear

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate change $x=X-4, y=Y+1$ should do the trick. Expand the polynomial in $X, Y$ then switch back to the original coordinates.

Comment: By making this change of variables, the expression I will get will be the Taylor expansion around $(-4,1) $ ? THanks !

Comment: @CrazyStatistician: Of course. You have the polynomial $p(x,y)$. You apply the change of variables $$\begin{cases} p(x, y)=P(X, Y) \\ x=X-4\\y=Y+1\end{cases}$$ and compute $P(X, Y)$ explicitly. You get an expression in powers of $X=x+4, Y=y-1$. This is exactly the Taylor poynomial you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$x^3=(x+4)^3-12x^2-48x-64 \tag 1$$

$$xy=(x+4)(y-1)-4y+(x+4)\tag 2$$

$$x^2=(x+4)^2-8x-16 \tag 3$$

$$x=(x+4)-4\tag 4$$

Using $(1)$, $(3)$, and $(4)$ gives

$$x^3=(x+4)^3-12(x+4)^2+48(x+4)-64 $$

$$x^2=(x+4)^2-8(x+4)+16$$

Using $(2)$ and $(4)$ gives

$$xy=(x+4)(y-1)+(x+4)-4(y-1)-4$$

Just combine terms and you will have it!

Comment: Nice one ! Thanks a lot ! It's a shame that I cannot accept two answers for my question. Thanks !

Comment: You can give a vote up.